# Test coverage is 0% - but I wrote test logic

Tags: apex, unit-test

class:

```
public class CaseCommentsCtr {
public Id     AttributeCaseId    {get; set;}

public List<CaseComment> getCaseComments() {
    return [
      SELECT CommentBody
      FROM CaseComment
      WHERE ParentId = :this.AttributeCaseId
      ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC limit 1
    ];
}
```

}

Test class:

```
  @isTest
  private class CaseCommentsCtrTracker{


static void CaseCommentsCtrTest(){
     CaseCommentsCtr  patr= new CaseCommentsCtr ();
     patr.AttributeCaseId='test';

     Id CaseRTId = Case.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('AMD').getRecordTypeId();

     Case case1=new Case();


        case1.recordtypeid =CaseRTId ;
        case1.Status ='New';

        case1.Subject='test';

        insert case1;

     casecomment comm = new casecomment();
        comm.commentbody = 'testing';
        comm.IsPublished=true;
        comm.parentid = case1.id;
        comm.CreatedDate= system.today();

        insert comm;
        try {
                patr.getCaseComments();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

}
```

}

Comment: Articles like [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests) are a good place to start so you can figure it out yourself.

Comment: Hi keith i have written test class but its not getting covered but its not getting covered

Comment: You are missing the `testMethod` keyword or `@IsTest` annotation on your `CaseCommentsCtrTest ` test method.

Comment: Happens to us all.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this method is not consider to be test methode.
please check:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

I prefere to use this notation:

```
static testMethod void test(){}
```

Comment: I like `@isTest static void test() {}` to allow for test annotation attributes if required.  Strictly personal preference